# Performing different types of Observables in sequence with RxJava/RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have a remote call(retrofit) - which I converted into an Observable. Let's call it Observable Y.
Now, I also have a certain code that looks for geo location with GPS and NETWORK providers. I have a Timer there, that basically limits the time that the geo search can be performed for. Let's call it Task X. I want to convert it into an Observable X.

Then, I want to have a subcription, that will perform Observable X(that is, find location), once it will return a Location, I will "analyze" in a certain way, and then I will either pass that Location into the Observable Y(the retrofit call), or simply quit(if that "raw" location will be enough in my case)

At ALL time, I want to be able to interrupt all that "process". From what I gather, I can achieve that by simply unsubscribing the subscription, right?
and then next time just subscribe this subscription once again in the future.

Questions:

```
1. Can all of that be implemented via RxJava/RxAndroid ?
2. Does it even make sense implementing it with Rx ? or is there a more efficient way?
3. How is it done with Rx? 
(More specifically : (a) How do I convert task Y into an Observable Y?
                     (b) How do I perform them in sequence with only one subscription?)
```

Comment: you should avoid to ask composed question on stackoverflow ... it can be dowvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- It can be implemented via RxJava

2- This is your best option so far

3-

3-a [Observable.fromCallable()](https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/02/21/rxjava-part-2-creating-an-observable/) does the trick

3-b [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator is used to chain observable calls
you can proceed like this:

```
private Location searchForLocation() {
    // of course you will return not null location
    return null;
}

// your task X
//mock your location fetching
private Observable<Location> getLocationObservableX() {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> searchForLocation());
}

//your task Y
//replace CustomData with simple String
//just to mock your asynchronous retrofit call
private Observable<List<String>> getRetrofitCallObservableY(String param){
    return Observable.just(new ArrayList<String>());
}


//subscribe
private void initialize() {
    getLocationObservableX()
            .filter(location -> {
                //place your if else here
                //condition
                //don't continue tu retrofit
                boolean condition = false;

                if (condition) {
                    //process
                    //quit and pass that Location in Broadcas
                    //you shall return false if you don't want to continue
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            //filter operation does not continue here if you return false
            .flatMap(location -> getRetrofitCallObservableY("param"))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                //do what you want with response
            });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I think there are just a couple of things that perhaps I've been misunderstood.
1. Both the Location fetching , and the Retrofit calls to server are Asynchronous.
2. The thing is that once I get a Location from the asynchronous method getLocationObservableX, I don't want to instantly go to getRetrofitCalObservable. I first want to analyze the Location I got, and then, in "if-else" statement either quit and pass that Location in Broadcast - OR - go to getRetrofitCallObservableY(location). so I need to add to something between `location` and  `-> getRetrofit...` .

Comment: also, my retorfit operation looks like this :
`@GET("/myserver/mydata")
DisposableObserver<List<CustomData>> getMyDataRxAndroid(@Query("param") String param);`

Comment: I understand, I will update the answer to solve your if-else problem

Comment: Thank you. just one thing I'm not clear on.. As I mentioned earlier, `searchForLocation` is not a sync method, but rather an Async method - when fetching google location, I have the different LocationListeners(gps, networks..), that I'm waiting for their response. Also a timer, if no one from the locationlisteners returns a response in X time, I try to get the "last known location". And then send the Location. How can I transform all that into an Observable?

Comment: you can create a Publishsubject wich emit Location in each listeners. Then you can use timeout operator and onErrorReturn operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173453/discussion-between-bvtp-and-maheryhaja).